# Best German expression for being metaphorically "rusty"

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

What would be the most natural way of saying in German that one is "rusty" at a particular skill/language?

I have used "verrostet" myself and while native speakers have caught my meaning, I don't think I've heard them saying that themselves, so I'm wondering what the most idiomatic expression is.

Comment: Greetings, thanks and the like are discouraged on the SE network. I took the liberty to edit your "Thanks" out, even though I figure you know by the fact, that you got the association bonus ;) Welcome to [german.se]

Comment: I'm the same as Phe0nix, can't comment, can only "answer the question" sorry... was the issue of "außer Übung sein" vs "eingerostet" resolved? is there basically no way of saying 'I'm a little rusty' (or 'I'm rusty' etc...) in German? would you just say 'I'm out of practice?' or are there just two different ways of expressing the point?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use

> eingerostet

as in

> Meine Deutschkenntnisse sind schon etwas eingerostet.
>   *My German is a little rusty.*

In English - if I'm not mistaken - it's possible to attribute "rusty" to people:

> I'm a little rusty [at something].

Although I hear it occasionally, 
I'm not quite sure the same applies to German. To me, it feels more natural to label the respective skill/language as rusty. On the other hand, this dialogue seems fine:

> Kannst du noch Basketball spielen?
>
> -- Puh, ich bin schon etwas eingerostet.

Although in this case, the "rustyness" does not explicitly refer to basketball, rather to his/her overall fitness, as Em1 pointed out.

Comment: In deinem Basketball-Beispiel würde ich das so verstehen, dass dieser jemand selten bis nie Sport macht und ziemlich unfit ist.

Comment: So negativ würde ich das zwar nicht auffassen (*etwas*), aber du hast recht, es bezieht sich nicht explizit auf Basketball. Ich bau's ein.

Comment: "Ich bin ein wenig eingerostet" is something people actually say if they need to convey the meaning that they're out of practice but can get into the swing of things with a little exercise. Especially elderly people use this idiom, referring to the old proverb "Wer rastet, der rostet." ("Who rests, rusts.").

Answer (score 5):

I would probably use "aus der Übung sein", literally "being out of practise". It sounds a bit more natural to me than "eingerostet".

Comment: I usually say `außer Übung sein`. Somehow makes more sense to me than `aus der Übung sein`.

Comment: I'm sorry to Post this as an answer, but my reputation is too low to add a comment. @Subhamoy Sengupta in themik81's Answer: > außer Übung sein means "to be except Exercise" in english. And yes, that doesn't make sense in any of both Languages ;) What I want to say is simply, that "außer" is german for "except". Your Luck is, that "außer" sounds like "aus'er" which is lazy speach for "aus der", which makes perfect sense and was themik81's answer.

Comment: @Phe0nix: Is that not just literal translation? außer can mean other things too, as in `außer Betrieb`, which does not mean `except operation`, but `out of order`. If there is something that people do not use any more, it is `außer Anwendung`. There are various other cases, I am sure.

Comment: @Phe0nix: While I would somehow prefer *aus der Übung sein*, I agree with Subhamoy that insisting on translating *außer* to *except* is pointless here. [*außer Atem* (out of breath) and *außer Sicht* (out of sight)](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/au%C3%9Fer%20Atem) are two more frequently used expressions, and they have nothing to do with *except* in the sense that establishes an exception from what was mentioned before.

Comment: (I'm very sorry for making such a hassle with my answers) @Subhamoy Sengupta again: (and partly @ O. R. Mapper) You're right in the examples you have given. I'm sorry I overlooked that use of außer, now I can see your point. But in the case above you don't use the word "Übung" like you use e.g. "Betrieb" in your examples.
I can't really explain it, i think it's because of the -ng, because you also don't say "ich bin völlig außer Fassung" but "ich bin völlig aus der Fassung". All I know for sure is, that you won't say it like that in german (I'm a native german speaker, which makes me quite con

Comment: @Phe0nix To me, the two seem interchangeable. (*Ich bin außer Übung* vs. *Ich bin aus der Übung*) [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Uebung) agrees.

Comment: It appears that this discussion is becoming entirely **off topic** to the question above. Consider making this a new Question/Answer thread on the usage of *außer* or *aus der*.

Comment: @Takkat Seems resolved.

Comment: We can't leave the comments here, because they are **off topic** on this question - however the discussion is valuable and should not go away. Why not make it a new question with answers? We don't have that topic yet. Wink mit dem Zaunpfahl an @Phe0nix - du brauchst Reputationspunkte ;)

Comment: @Takkat But they are directly related to the answer?.

Comment: @Carlster: this site is designed to answer questions, not to discuss answers. What we have here should be a new topic.